# Incorrect stack trace from an exception in a method copied from a groovy shell script

Tags: groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a groovy script that defines a method which throws an exception.
Using AST Transformations I generate at compile time a new class.
Then I copy this method from the script to this new class and make the class available at runtime.
When at runtime I create a new object of the new class and call the method in stack trace I can see references to `Script1` class instead of the new generated class.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException
at MyGeneratedClass.myMethod(Script1.groovy:4)
at MyGeneratedClass$myMethod.call(Unknown Source)
at scripttest.ExTest.main(ExTest.groovy:35)
```

Is there anything I can do to change it so I don't see this `Script1.groovy` class in stack trace but the new class and line number within it?

My code:

```
class ExTest {

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        String script = '''
def myMethod() {
        throw new RuntimeException()
}
'''
        def config = new CompilerConfiguration()
        config.addCompilationCustomizers(new MyCompilerConfiguration())
        ClassLoader classLoaderToUse = new GroovyClassLoader()
        GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(classLoaderToUse, new Binding(), config)
        Script parsedScript = shell.parse(script)
        def generatedClass = parsedScript.class.fields.find {it.name == 'myGeneratedClassField'}.type
        def generated = generatedClass.newInstance()
        generated.myMethod()
    }
}

class MyCompilerConfiguration extends CompilationCustomizer {

    MyCompilerConfiguration() {
        super(CompilePhase.CONVERSION)
    }

    @Override
    void call(SourceUnit source, GeneratorContext context, ClassNode currentClassNode) throws CompilationFailedException {
        def newClassAst = new AstBuilder().buildFromSpec {
            classNode('MyGeneratedClass', ClassNode.ACC_PUBLIC) {
                classNode java.lang.Object
                interfaces { classNode GroovyObject }
                mixins { }
            }
        }
        ClassNode myGeneratedClassNode = newClassAst[0]
        source.getAST().addClass(myGeneratedClassNode)
        currentClassNode.addField('myGeneratedClassField', Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, myGeneratedClassNode, new EmptyExpression())
        MethodNode myMethodNode = source.getAST().methods.find {it.name == 'myMethod'}
        myGeneratedClassNode.addMethod(myMethodNode.name, Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, myMethodNode.returnType, myMethodNode.parameters, myMethodNode.exceptions, myMethodNode.code)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stacktrace is correct, the `Script1.groovy:4` you see is not the name of a class, but the name of the file which has generated this class, which is, in your case, a Groovy File.

This name come from the `CodeSource` instance present in the `CompilationUnit` associated with the `ClassNode`. You can change it by using a `GroovyCodeSource` in methods like `GroovyShell.parse` or `GroovyClassLoader.parseClass`, but I think it's a really bad idea ! (security, debugging and other thinks are related to this object)